# Use GPL licensed software externally?

Tags: licensing, gpl, gpl-2

I want to use scapy for my commercial project but scapy is licensed GPLv2. I use scapy as a parser for packets and I wonder if it is OK if I create a separate wrapper module using scapy and get input and pass output via ZeroMQ or another Message broker. I am OK with licensing my wrapper module under GPL but do I have to license my other components/modules under GPL?

Comment: See https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/7495/11412 which summarizes conventional wisdom on programs which interact by means of network sockets and exchange information that is not excessively intimate.

Comment: @mugetsu, if you haven't read the linked questions, you really should.  If you have, you should edit your question to indicate what, if anything, is not answered by them.  Otherwise, I fear your question may get closed by the community.